# SQL Server : What does Lost I/O mean?

Tags: sql-server

I came across the term 'Lost I/O' in the MSDN Article on [Lost I/O](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337525%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It says :
"A long-I/O message may indicate that an I/O is permanently blocked and will never complete (known as lost I/O), or merely that it just has not completed yet. It is not possible to tell from the message which scenario is the case, although a lost I/O will often lead to a latch time-out."

Apart from the reference to the term 'Lost I/O', I couldn't find it referenced anywhere else. Any article or further explanation on things like why a lost I/O occurs etc?

Comment: You didnt google this a lot did you? [SQL Server logs "Msg 833" when I/O delay problems occur](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2137408?wa=wsignin1.0) and [MSSQLSERVER_833](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337269.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I did @AdriaanStander ; I did Google a lot. But Message 833 could mean Long I/O or a Stalled I/O too. I'm looking specifically for info on 'Lost' I/O.